# c# Parsing error when colliding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax-error

I keep Geting parsing errors from this c# script by the way im kind of new to c#
please help me

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Scripty : MonoBehaviour {

public float moveSpeed = 10f;

private Rigidbody rbody;
private Renderer rend;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rend = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    float inputX = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float inputZ = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    float moveX = inputX *moveSpeed*Time.deltaTime;
    float moveZ = inputZ*moveSpeed*Time.deltaTime;


    //transform.Translate(moveX,0f,moveZ);
    rbody.AddForce(moveX,0f,moveZ);
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    if (col.collider.name == "Wall (1)") {
        rend.material.color = Color.blue;
    }
    else if(col.collider.name == "Wall (2)") 
    {
        rend.material.color = Color.red;
    }
    else if(col.collider.name == "Wall (3)") 
    {
        rend.material.color = Color.green;
    }
    else if(col.collider.name == "Wall (4)") 
    {
        rend.material.color = Color.yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting

Comment: I think you miss, one last barcket: }.

Comment: In which line you are getting error?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a brace at the end. The `class` does not have a closing brace.